# get news from websites to my website wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping

I want a way to bring news from websites to my website, and that makes changes to the article so as not to cause copyright problems. I use my website, WordPress.

I have used a plugin that brings up articles called Octolooks Scrapes, but it brings me wrong articles and does not edit the article. This is a mistake, so I would like a way through the plugin or something else.

Answer (score -1):

There are mainly 2 things you can do here:

1. Use RSS Feeds: Many websites provide RSS feeds that allow you to syndicate their content. You can use the built-in RSS feed functionality in WordPress to import and display content from other sources.If the website you are trying to get the data from uses Wordpress you can visit the URL of that website concatenated with a /feed.
2. Building Your Own Web scraper For the specific website/blog that you are trying to get the data from.

I highly encourage you to read about RSS Feeds especially the one in Wordpress. Link to documentation: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/wordpress-feeds/

Answer (score -1):

Integrate a news API:

https://newsapi.org/

https://rapidapi.com/blog/rapidapi-featured-news-apis/

Or any specific topics you want I'm sure there are APIs for those too.

Comment: how do I edit this news automatically without writing anything?

Answer (score -2):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/news-parser/

https://www.news-parser.com/

The News Parser plugin allows you to retrieve data from both RSS feeds manually or in automatic mode. It offers flexible customization options and integrates with the OpenAI API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35524175)